# Wolfram Alpha: How to solve a system of linear equations with variable terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to use Wolfram Alpha to solve the following system of equations (for $x, y$; given $ad - bc \neq 0$) in order to confirm that I solved it correctly by hand:

$$
ax + by = 3 \\
cx + dy = -4
$$

Wolfram Alpha [does not understand](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+ax%2Bby+%3D+3%2C+cx%2Bdy+%3D+-4+for+x%2C+y) this syntax:

```
solve ax+by = 3, cx+dy = -4 for x, y
```

However strangely it [does understand](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+ax%2Bby+%3D+3%2C+cx%2By+%3D+-4+for+x%2C+y) this ($y$ instead of $dy$ in the second equation):

```
solve ax+by = 3, cx+y = -4 for x, y
```

What is the correct syntax to solve this system of equations?

Comment: dy is surely recognized as the differential element in an integral. An advice: introduce the multiplication sign everywhere $a*x+b*y=$... etc.

Comment: In calculus, $dy$ is standard notation for the differential of $y$, so WolframAlpha gets confused. Use another letter as a variable instead of $d$.

Comment: That was it. Using the multiplication symbol or another letter as a variable worked. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, $dy$ is the standard notation for the differential of $y$ in calculus. Using a different variable, like $hy$, would work. So does multiplying the two variables, such as $d\cdot y.$